# Partial connection to SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sqlmembershipprovider, sql-server-2014-express

Firstly, this is *not* a repeat of the same old:

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified.

Here's the scenario. I'm using ASP.NET membership with a `SQLMembershipProvider`. This used to work fine, however since a clean install on my development machine and upgrading to SQL Server 2014 Express, I'm now experiencing a strange issue.

When I run the website I get the login form. If I enter an incorrect username and password I get the normal message "invalid username/password". If I enter the correct username / password I get the error 26 as above. I can successfully connect to the database using the same connection string in SQL Server Management Studio, just not from within my ASP.NET Web App.

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings> 
   <add name="WEBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Server=SERSQL01\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WEBAPP;User ID=MyLogin;Password=MyPassword"         
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   />
</connectionStrings>
```

Things I have checked:

- Instance name is correct.
- Firewall is disabled.
- Remote connections are enabled.
- TCP/IP enabled, port 1433.
- SQL Browser Enabled.
- Mixed mode authentication is enabled.
- Telnet connects successfully.
- SSSM connects successfully.

Environment:

- Development Machine: Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013
- Server: SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: `Initial Catalog=WEBAPP.MDF` ?  Here you should have the logical database name, not the name of the MDF file

Comment: @Steve, thanks, somehow when I attached the database I incorrectly renamed it to "WEBAPP.MDF".  I have renamed the database too "WEBAPP" and changed the connection string as above.  The problem still exists.

Comment: @Steve,  any other ideas?  Still struggling with this one.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. Not an expert in SqlMemberShipProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

I was using a custom sql membership provider.   But I hadn't extended the role provider:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider" >
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
              connectionStringName="WEBConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```